# Programmatically get the binding Name

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

Need to get the name of binding object in code  behind .

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="grdCoverContent" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserInsertRows="False" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                                            GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8"   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                            ShowGroupPanel="False" ItemsSource="{Binding CoverContentCollection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True }" 
                                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCoverContent,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Source={StaticResource CoverViewModel} }" RowHeight="30" CellValidating="grdCoverContent_CellValidating" >
```

Is there any way to get binding name as "CoverContentCollection"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is actually the Binding's `Path` (actually it's the `Path` property of the `PropertyPath`). So just get the binding and access its Path like this:

```
var path = grdCoverContent.GetBindingExpression(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty)
                          .ParentBinding.Path.Path;
```

The code should be run when the window has been loaded.